# Nonsingular block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, block-matrices

Let us consider a matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and the block partitioning
$$
\mathbf{A} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{A}_{11} & \mathbf{A}_{12} \\
\mathbf{A}_{21} & \mathbf{A}_{22} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I have found some lecture notes that claim that the two conditions
$$
\det(\mathbf{A}_{11}) \neq 0\quad \mathrm{and} \quad \det(\mathbf{A}_{22}) \neq 0
$$
are sufficient for the nonsingularity of $\mathbf{A}$. It seems to be false to me, as for example
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
verify the two conditions but is singular. Is there a missing condition or something?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you link to the lecture notes?

Comment: @GitGud [link](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~rootzen/highdimensional/blockmatrixinverse.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A$ is invertible if $\det(A_{11})\ne 0$, $\det(A_{22})\ne 0$, and $A_{12}=0$. Ie. $A$ is block upper-triagonal.

Invertibility of all four blockse does not imply invertibility of the matrix, as you showed.

Non-Invertibility of all four blocks also does not imply non-invertibility of $A$
$$
A=\left( \begin{array}{cc|cc}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{array}\right)
$$
all four blocks are singular, but $A$ is invertible.