# Singularity of a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, block-matrices

When is the following matrix singular?

$$\begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{bmatrix}$$

I've found on the internet that if $A,B,C,$ or $D$ is non-singular and its Schur complements is non-singular then the whole block matrix is non-singular. But how to deal with the situation when every one of them are singular? I mean, what's the conditions for the block matrix so that it is not singular?

Comment: When you say "how to deal with" what do you mean? Are you trying to solve a system? Are you asking if these conditions are necessary (you've already found them to be sufficient)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was basically trying to find out the conditions when the block matrix is non-singular. Thanks. P.S. I've edited the question

Comment: I've been thinking about this in terms of non-zero determinants and from this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices it looks like there are several sufficient conditions, but I can't find any necessary ones. I think there are even examples where all four are singular and the bock matrix is non-singular.

Comment: Yeah, there is one with every singular submatrices but with the whole non-singular  matrix

Comment: @Tpofofn This link says that if those conditions hold the lemma is true, but it doesn't say that those conditions are necessary for invertibility. For example the block matrix \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} is its own inverse, but each 2 by 2 block is singular.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2913018/721644) might be interesting as well as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3093802/721644). That's all I found on MSE. 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nonsingular block matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746435/nonsingular-block-matrix)

Comment: @ShawSa, you there is the same lemma in the thread above. 