# Is $A-BDC$ non-singular in a non-singular block matrix?

Tags: matrices, block-matrices

Let $$ M = \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{bmatrix} $$ be a non-singular block matrix where $A\in\mathbb R^{p\times p}$ and $D\in\mathbb R^{q\times q}$. I suspected that if $p< q$ then $A-BDC$ is a non-singular matrix.

I have tried hard to find a counter-example with no luck. So I tried to prove it. This is where I hit several dead-ends.

First, if you left-multiply $\begin{bmatrix}I&-B\\0&I\end{bmatrix}$ and right-multiply $\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\C&I\end{bmatrix}$ to $M$, you'll get
$$\begin{bmatrix}A-BDC&B(I-D)\\(I+D)C&D\end{bmatrix}$$
but this wouldn't lead to any conclusion.

I also tried to use a pseudo-inverse approach on $[A\quad B]$ but the results are disappointing. So I would appreciate any hints or counter-examples to put an end to this problem.

Comment: Even in a $2 \times 2$ nonsingular matrix you may get $0$ for your expression.

Comment: @GEdgar I have made a mistake in wording the question. I should have said $p<q$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block matrix
$$
   M = \left[\!\begin{array}{c|cc}0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\!\right]
$$
is non-singular, yet we get
$$
   A - BDC = 0 - \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = 0.
$$